# How can i run a model trained on GPU in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

Title.I use spacy2.2.3 to train a new model,so i code that in cmd in windows7：

```
python -m spacy train -g -1 zh models train_path dev_path
```

Also,i install cupy-cuda101,version 7.2.0. When coding in python3.7.6:

```
import spacy
spacy.prefer_gpu()
spacy.require_gpu()
```

They both print "True".

I use '-g -1' because i want to train it on gpu,and i learnt this by help option.
And then,i opened taskmgr as well as GPU-Z,the result told me it still run on cpu instead of gpu.

What cause it?I am pretty new in this. Who can help me?

System:Windows 7

GPU :GT740

Comment: By the way,i have installed cuda10.1 and cudnn7.6.4,i am certain about cuda path should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- `-g -1` disables the GPU, the option to enable the GPU is `-g 0` or `-g 1` or whichever GPU ID you want it to use
- there's a major bug in the GPU support for windows in spacy v2.2.3, so you want to train on CPU only in windows (leave out `-g` or use `-g -1` like above) until v2.2.4 is released